# How to implement symbol-length procedure in scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I am new to functional programming and trying to implement a procedure that returns the length of a symbol. Here is what i think: I give one parameter to it named "inSym" to return its length.

```
(define symbol-length (lambda (inSym) ( ...) )
```

But, i do not know how do i iterate over the inSym to find the number of characters in it. Can anyone give some help? Note that i do not want to use any built in functions or convert symbol into a string.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't iterate over the symbol. Instead, convert the symbol to a string (`symbol->string`) and get its length (`string-length`).

Comment: Thanks, but actually in the exercise it is forbidden to convert it into a string, or using a built in function. Any other hints can you give?

Comment: Can you describe your exercise in more detail? In standard Scheme, that's the _only_ way to get a symbol's length. You may be using a special Scheme system that lets you do it a different way.